# Why is a before_action not executed when the action is called from respond_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, before-filter

I have an action, which sets an instance veriable before `:edit` and `:new` actions in a controller. This works if I call these actions directly in a request. However, if I call `:update` or `:create` and they fail, after which within a `respond_to` block `format.html { render action: :edit }` is executed, the `before_action` does not get triggered. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `render action: :edit` doesn't actually call controller action, but only renders `edit` template.

You'll find more info in Rails guides:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#the-difference-between-render-and-redirect-to

Comment: I thought so, but how do you solve the problem with the callbacks? I found this [really nice article](http://jgaskins.org/blog/2014/08/25/better-alternative-to-rails-before_action-to-load-objects) about creating helper methods, which memoize instance vartiables. Is this the way to go or is there a better solution?